Public Variables in Forms with Multiple Copies
I have written a process where a form can be created a multiple of times - each copy relating to a particular value in a variable at the time of creation.
I use :-
Dim FormA As New FormX
FormA.Show()

The process works perfectly and I often have half a dozen copies of the form on the desktop
I would however like to reference a public variable inside a copy of that form.
Is it possible to specify which copy of the form I wish to reference ? because obviously FormA.Varname is not specific to a copy of FormX

"because obviously FormA.Varname is not specific to a copy of FormX" - Um.... yes it is.  For example, you can call .Show() on FormA and it will show that specific instance of the form.  Which you claim works as expected.  Can you clarify what problem you are observing and provide a [mcve] which demonstrates that problem?

Presumably you actually used FormX.VarName.  Legal syntax in vb.net, not helpful to meet your goal.  You'll have to keep track of these copies, nothing that a List(Of FormX) cannot do.  Add to it in the form constructor, remove with the Disposed event.

FormA is just a variable. FormX is just a class. Like any other class you can create as many instances as you need and assign them to different variables. You might even have several variables to refer to the same instance.
So then, if you need to distinguish your form instances, each instance needs it's own reference in it's own variable. You might keep these in, say, a List(Of FormX), but that's not the only option. There are many ways you might want to keep track of them... in fact, there are as many options as there are programmers in the world, so without a lot more detail about how this is used that's as much help as we can offer.
The tricky part here is you'll likely also want to clean them up when a form closes. But this isn't something .NET provides for you. You'll need to write the code to do this work yourself.

I agree with Joel Coehoorn, you should maintain some kind of List of your forms on your own.
...but VB.Net also keeps a list for you in Application.OpenForms(). You can iterate over that and find the one you're looking for.
For example, given FormX with a public variable called SomeVariable:
Public Class FormX

    Public SomeVariable As String

End Class

Here's how we could find the instance that has "tacosauce" in SomeVariable:
For Each fx As FormX In Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of FormX)
    If fx.SomeVariable = "tacosauce" Then
        ' ... do something with "fx" ...
        fx.Text = "Yum...tacos!"
        Exit For ' <-- leave the loop now?
    End If
Next

Note that the .OfType(Of FormX) keeps us from trying to process other of types of Forms that might be open.

So you have a Form, let's call it MainForm, that creates one or more other Forms,  let's call them SubForm1, SubForm2, etc. All sub forms are of the same class, let's call it class SubForm.

I would however like to reference a public variable inside a copy of that form.

Who is I, the MainForm? And who are that form and the copy of that form?
I'm not sure if you want that the MainForm changes a variable in only SubForm2, or if you want that MainForm fetches the value from SubForm1 and sets this in the corresponding value in SubForm2.
Surely that is not a problem, just do it. However Changing a variable in a Form does not automatically change the visual display of the variable.
In other words, if your SubForm class has a variable MyProperty and a label LabelDisplayedProperty, that should always display the value of MyProperty, then changing the value of MyProperty is not enough.
The easiest way to do this, is to not separate MyProperty and LabelDisplayedProperty. Make a property MyProperty. This property will not change a variable myProperty, but directly change the value of the label.
I'm not really familiar with VB.Net, the following might contain syntax errors. However, I assume you'll get the gist:
Dim MyProperty As String
    Get
        Return LabelDisplayedProperty.Text;
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        LabelDisplayedProperty.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property

Usage in MainForm:
Dim SubForm1 As New SubForm
SubForm1.Show()
Dim SubForm2 As New SubForm
SubForm2.Show()

// get the displayed value from SubForm1 and put it in SubForm2
SubForm2.MyProperty = SubForm1.MyProperty

This works also if the displayed value is not a label but an edit box. If the operator has changed the value, then you'll always get the value of that the operator typed.
This works fine if the property is of a similar type as the displayed value. However, if the property is of a different type than the displayed value, it might be better to remember the set value:
    Dim MyVariable As Int // TODO: make this variable local
    Dim MyProperty As Int
    Get
        Return MyVariable
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Int)
        MyVariable = Value
        LabelDisplayedProperty.Text = Value.ToString
    End Set
End Property

The usage will be the same.
If you want that the changes that the operator makes in SubForm1 are automatically updated in SubForm2, then you should raise an Event whenever class SubForm.MyProperty changes value.
MainForm should subscribe to this event, and whenever the event is raised, MainForm should read the new value and set it to the values in the other SubForms that should have the same value.
I would not advice to let SubForm1 communicate with SubForm2 directly, after all, officially the subforms wouldn't know about each others existence, there are periods that not all SubForms exist (yet or anymore). If you would let the forms directly communicate with each other, you'll have to tell each form about the existence of the other forms that it should communicate this. You should also tell the SubForm when not to communicate because the other SubForm doesn't exist anymore. This administration is way more complicated than to handle the changes via the MainForm.
As said before, I'm not really familiar with VB.NET. If desired I could give you an example in C#. If you are not familiar with event handling in VB.NET, consider to read some background information about this.
